# Como faço para ver a quantidade que a função retorna Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Fiz um script que me retorna os nomes de jogadores online de um determinado jogo
só que eu queria tbm colocar a quantidade. Como seria essa estrutura para retorno da quantidade? Já tentei criar uma lista e com ela usar a função len mais ele da erro.

```
import requests
import json

def Expert_serve():

    serve = "expert"
    url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
    response = url.json()
    for i in range(100):              
        if "IFATC" in response[i]["DisplayName"]:
            print(response[i]['DisplayName'])



teste = (Expert_serve())

print ('Jogadores online {}'.fotmat (len(teste))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque seu programa não está retornando os jogadores, apenas imprimindo seus nomes. Você pode montar uma lista (no exemplo feito com [compreensão de lista](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compreens%C3%A3o_de_lista)), usá-la como retorno da função, para então obter seu tamanho:

```
import requests
import json

def Expert_serve():    
    serve = "expert"
    url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
    response = url.json()
    listaDeJogadores = [response[i]["DisplayName"] for i in range(100) if  "IFATC" in response[i]["DisplayName"]]
    return listaDeJogadores


lista = Expert_serve()
print("Lista de jogadores: ", lista)    
print ('Jogadores online: ',len(lista))
```